# Update app widget layout dynamically

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I'm working on a voip/sip based application which is capable of making calls from a dialpad widget which has the four buttons at the bottom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ibtn_handsfree"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_dialpad_action_button"
    android:src="@drawable/selector_handsfree" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ibtn_headset"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_dialpad_action_button"
    android:src="@drawable/selector_headset" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ibtn_copyToDir"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_dialpad_action_button"
    android:src="@drawable/selector_copytodir" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ibtn_keyboard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_dialpad_action_button"
    android:src="@drawable/selector_keyboard" />
<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/ibtn_sendkey_widget"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_dialpad_action_button"
    android:src="@drawable/selector_send_key_dialer"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

1. Is it discouraged that I toggle the visibility of any of my layout
   elements dynamically ? For example if I wish to hide the fourth
   button, depending on any active call present(which I believe would
   require an individual and dedicated listener attached).
2. If the dynamic changes on the widget layout aren't discouraged, how
   do I go about doing that ?

Appreciate your thoughts and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the answer for the first question, but in order to toggle visibility of a button in a widget:

- Add [`setOnClickPendingIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent%28int,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) for the button
- Listen for that intent in your `AppWidgetProvider`'s `onReceive`
- Toggle visibility of the element and [`updateAppWidget`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#updateAppWidget%28int%5B%5D,%20android.widget.RemoteViews%29)

Comment: Hey, yea I know that much, but I need to toggle the visibility whenever there is a change in the call state of the application, which could be quite frequent.

Comment: Even if so, the above holds. All you need to do is listen to call state change and update the visibility accordingly.

Comment: And I believe,for listening to that event I will need a dedicated service specially for that..

Comment: Yeah, maybe. But your question was not about how to listen to phone state changes, was not it?